# wicked-pdf not rendering pdf correctly. show_html looks fine, pdf downloaded looks awful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

I'm using wickedpdf to try to generate a nice looking pdf report. When using show_as_html: true to make sure everything looks right, the page looks great, it uses the correct template, and all content is loaded as they should. There are no reference errors or asset errors, those were corrected by creating a wickedpdf specific scss and js (see below):

[image]

However, when I set it up to disposition: 'attachment' for it to actually generate the pdf, it looks nothing like the page above and the result is a pdf that lacks formatting and with disjointed components across multiple pages. The graphs are also not rendering and show no data. It seems like it's not applying the correct bootstrap/custom css and it's not running the javascript files needed to create the layout as shown on the html view. Any ideas why this is happening? My understanding is using show_as_html: true would render the exact same page as it would look in the pdf and then creating the pdf would use those exact contents to create the pdf document. I've looked at all other wicked-pdf questions but I haven't found anything that helps.

[image]

[image]

Below is the current setup in the controller:

```
format.pdf do
            render pdf: "#{@interest.name}",
            template: "interests/pdf_export.html.erb",
            layout: 'pdf.html', disposition: 'attachment',
            title: "#{@interest.name}",
            #default_header: true,
            #default_footer: true,
            header: {   spacing: 10,
                        html: {            
                        content: "interests/report_header",
                        layout:   'pdf.html',             # optional, use 'pdf_plain' for a pdf_plain.html.pdf.erb file, defaults to main layout
                        }
                    },
        viewport_size: '1280x1024',
        #show_as_html: true,
        javascript_delay: 10000,
        enable_plugins: true,
        page_size: 'A4'
      end
```

Here is the pdf layout:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PDF</title>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'wickedpdf' %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">




  <!-- JAVASCRIPT DEPENDENCIES ---->
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- popper -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.19.0/feather.js"></script>

  <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'wickedpdf'%>

</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

wickedpdf.scss:

```
@import 'stack/bootstrap';

@import 'stack/fonts/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon';
@import 'stack/vendors/extensions/pace';

@import 'stack/vendors/extensions/unslider';
@import 'stack/plugins/extensions/noui-slider';

@import "stack/bootstrap-extended";
@import "stack/colors";
@import "wickedpdf/components";

@import 'stack/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu';
@import 'stack/core/colors/palette-gradient';
@import 'style';
```

wickedpdf.js:

```
//= require stack/vendors/vendors.min
//= require stack/vendors/charts/raphael-min
//= require stack/vendors/charts/chart.min
//= require stack/vendors/charts/jquery.sparkline.min
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/unslider-min
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/wNumb
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/nouislider.min
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/jquery.steps.min
//= require stack/vendors/timeline/horizontal-timeline
//= require stack/vendors/tables/datatable/datatables.min
//= require stack/core/app-menu
//= require stack/core/app
//= require stack/scripts/pages/dashboard-ecommerce
//= require_tree ./common
//= stub ./common/subscriptions
```

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is using show_as_html: true would render the exact same page as it would look in the pdf

This is a misunderstanding. I'm sorry it may have seemed that way from whatever documentation you read, but `show_as_html: true` will display the HTML that will be sent to `wkhtmltopdf`, however `wkhtmltopdf` is like a very old version of Chrome (around version 13, I think). It doesn't support flexbox and a lot of nice things like that, which I think newer versions of Bootstrap need. Probably some of your JS libraries, too.

That option is there to help you more rapidly develop and debug. It's a lot tougher to view-source on a PDF.

My advice would be to strip away all CSS and JS first, and try and get the most important part working (the charts), then implement the layout with tables or floats or fixed-width containers, then copy over the bits of CSS you need specifically for the styles shown on the page, and not all of Bootstrap.

If this is a page that does double duty (both `format.html` and `format.pdf` versions are served), I would suggest breaking the PDF out into it's own separate template, so HTML visitors still get the beautiful interactive webpage.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going that route. I did try to strip everything out and leave just the js for the charts themselves, but even that didn't work. I ended up having to render the page as html, create images of the graphs once they completed drawing, and then exporting a different pdf template with the images of the graphs and no javascript dependencies. It added a lot of additional steps and checks, but I was not able to figure out a different way around this. I tested with multiple different versions of charts.js as well as multiple different parameters with no luck.

Comment: @Andrea That's a clever way around it, certainly. I've had reports of people needing to downgrade chart.js here: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/713

Comment: @Andrea Also, if you are pulling data via AJAX, the content-security-policy or relative routes might be getting in the way since it's rendered from a file on-disk.

Comment: Thanks. I tried downgrading but that didn't help. I wasn't pulling content via Ajax for the charts themselves, but I was having to pass data as data-variables from the backend into js so that could very well be it.